# Haskell, division sin div

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

Hola buenas tengo un problema en mano trata de hacer un código en Haskell con las siguientes condiciones:

Le introducimos dos numeros `a y b` para que se divida `a/b`  de tipo `Integer` , de forma que nos duevleva su modulo y su cocciente

Con las siguientes restrinciones solo se pueden usar sumas , restas y comparadores no se puede usar ni `div`, ni `mod`, ni nada

//Editado apartir de aqui

```
cocienteYResto:: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
cocienteYResto x y 
    | x < y = (x,?????)
    | otherwise = ((cocienteYResto (x - y) y))
```

bien aqui como vemos cuando `x< y` estoy devolviendo el resto, pero no tengo forma, bueno mas bien no se como conseguir ese cocciente (esto ahora mismo ni observa de que se divida entre `0`, ni de que `x<y` en un caso base

simplemente tiene que dividir cosas como 3/2 10/4, pero nada de 3/8 .

Se aceptan sugerencias de todo tipo, estoy empezando y toda ayuda me es buena.

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Si la multiplicación es un cúmulo de sumas, la división puedes verla como un cúmulo de restas.

Comment: Efectivamente así consigo sacar el resto, pero el cocciente mi idea era hacerf un contador por cada iteración (bueno mas que iteración la recursividad que tiene la función que tengo), pero claro! es Haskell y no existen variables dinámicas T_T

Comment: Pero puedes devolver `1 + division(a-b, b)`

Comment: no entiendo muy bien a que te refieres 1+ division(a-b,b) en un principio no me va a devolver nada, es decir division(a-b,b) solo va a devolverme cuando termine digamos la parte de recursividad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se podría hacer introduciendo una función auxiliar que fuera arrastrando el valor del cociente en cada iteración recursiva.

```haskell
cocienteYResto :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
cocienteYResto = aux 0
    where aux c x y
            | x >= y    = aux (c+1) (x-y) y
            | otherwise = (c,x)
```

Pero, puesto que estamos tratando de [programación-funcional](/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n-funcional), podemos aprovechar lo que tenemos para hacerlo más elegante:

```haskell
import Data.List (span, genericLength)

cocienteYResto :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
cocienteYResto x y = (genericLength l, head r)
    where (l,r) = (span (>=y) . iterate (-y+)) x
```

---

> *Editado el 2016-10-07*

Una versión mejor:

```haskell
cocienteYResto :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer)
cocienteYResto x y = head . dropWhile ((>=y).snd)
                   $ zip [0..] (iterate (-y+) x)
```

Comment: Gracias , me sirvió de mucha ayuda !